# Problem when importing data from csv to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I m trying to import data from a csv file to a database mysql that contains a column with type 'double'. 
So when i used the command load data infile i got good result only the field with type double it stays with the values of '0' in all lines.

I run this command :

```
load DATA INFILE 'd:/dropbox/Dropbox/applications/glimp/GlicemiaMisurazioni.csv'
  INTO TABLE iot_dataa
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (duration,date,fields1,fields2,fields3,fields4,rate,fields5,fields6,deviceid);
```

my csv file have this form
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdvzU.png)
but i get resualt as shown in this pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjEUf.png)

Comment: You're going to need to explain better because that description is not that clear. Can you give a specific example of a row you're importing, the schema, the query you use, and the results you're getting?

Comment: In csv there is a colmun that contains mesures of glucose (89,90...) i want to get it in my table that contains columns one of these columns named 'rate' with type double.

Comment: That's just a fraction of an example. We can't reproduce the problem from that alone.

Comment: I updated my question with more description.

Answer (score 0):

You can test by enter this command,

```
LOAD DATA INFILE *filename* INTO TABLE *tablename*
FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'char' [optionally] ENCLOSED BY 'char' ESCAPE BY 'char' 
LINES TERMINATED BY 'char'
```

for detial information, click [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)